# pip install -r requirements.txt fails on scipy, but works when run manually line-by-line

Tags: python, scipy, pip, virtualenv

I'm trying to run `pip install -r requirements.txt` inside a virtualenv using the following requirements.txt:

```
CherryPy==3.6.0
jellyfish==0.4.0
numpy==1.9.2
pygit2==0.20.3
scipy==0.15.1
```

But it fails on scipy with the following error message:

```
Command /usr/bin/python -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip_build_root/scipy/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-z6HBFi-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip_build_root/scipy
```

([Full log on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/SwTYxvV0))

If I try to manually run `pip install CherryPy==3.6.0`, then `pip install jellyfish==0.4.0`, ..., all the way to `pip install scipy==0.15.1` it works.

I eventually intend to make this requirements.txt be part of a docker image's `Dockerfile` build script (without using virtualenv inside the docker image) which is why I care that it works with `pip install -r requirements.txt`

Any ideas why it works manually but not automatically, and how to fix it?